# SDL_BlitSurface does not works

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have an issue with the SDL_BlitSurface...
When I blit (SDL_BlitSurface) in a transparent (background) surface, it does not blits, actually I tried all the existants functions (SDL_DisplayFormat(Alpha), SDL_SetAlpha, SDL_FilLRect/SDL_ColorKey, per-pixel method) anything! The r/g/b/a mask are good. Here is the code:

```
SDL_Surface * surfed_texture =
SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,surface_width,surface_height,32,
0x000000ff, 0x0000ff00, 0x00ff0000, 0xff000000);
Uint32 tormv = SDL_MapRGB(surfed_texture->format,255,0,255);
int possiblecolors[] = { 255,0,255,255,255,255 };
int in_pc = 0;
if(color.r == possiblecolors[0] && color.g == possiblecolors[1] && color.b == possiblecolors[2]){
in_pc=3;
}
SDL_FillRect(surfed_texture,NULL,SDL_MapRGB(surfed_texture
>format,possiblecolors[in_pc],possiblecolors[in_pc+1],possiblecolors[in_pc+2]));
SDL_SetColorKey(surfed_texture, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(surfed_texture
>format,possiblecolors[in_pc],possiblecolors[in_pc+1],possiblecolors[in_pc+2]));
SDL_Surface * temporal = NULL;
for(int i=0;i<(int)buff_split.size();i++){
const char* c_text = buff_split.at(i).c_str();

temporal = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font,c_text,color);

int w_fo;
int h_fo;
TTF_SizeText(font,c_text,&w_fo,&h_fo);

SDL_Rect rct;
rct.y=i*lineSkip;

if(txt_align==ALIGN_LEFT){
    rct.x=0;
}else if(txt_align==ALIGN_CENTER){
    rct.x = surface_width/2 - w_fo/2;
}else if(txt_align==ALIGN_RIGHT){
    rct.x = surface_width - w_fo;
}

rct.w=0;
rct.h=0;

// Blit surface

SDL_BlitSurface(temporal,NULL,surfed_texture,&rct);

SDL_FreeSurface(temporal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rendering on a software surface.
In my experience SDL2.0 only works with SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE not with
SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED ( flags supplied to SDL_CreateRenderer).

Gijs